# Установить время между 22.00 и 6.00(android)

Tags: java, android, время

Хочу сделать что б у пользователя была возможность выбрать время между определенным числом, к примеру между 22:00 и 6:00 но у меня не получается это реализовать, не знаю в чем дело.

```
public void setTime(final TextView setText) {
        String dateStart = "22:00:00";
        String dateStop = "06:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

            int mHour = Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24;
            int mMinute = Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60;

            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(context,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            setText.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
                        }

                    }, mHour, mMinute, true);
            tpd.show();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cant open time, sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Time error", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению родной компонент не поддерживает установку времени в интервале между минимальным допустимым и максимальным допустимым значением. Значения которые Вы передаете - `mHour, mMinute` - значения по умолчанию, которые будут установлены, когда `TimePickerDialog` откроется.

Для того чтобы установить диапазон, нужно использовать расширенный компонент (пример ниже):

```
/**
 * A time dialog that allows setting a min and max time.
 *
 */
public class RangeTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private int minHour = -1;
    private int minMinute = -1;

    private int maxHour = 25;
    private int maxMinute = 25;

    private int currentHour = 0;
    private int currentMinute = 0;

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DateFormat dateFormat;


    public RangeTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        currentHour = hourOfDay;
        currentMinute = minute;
        dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        try {
            Class<?> superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mTimePickerField = superclass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            mTimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimePickerField.get(this);
            mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    public void setMin(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMax(int hour, int minute) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        boolean validTime = true;
        if (hourOfDay < minHour || (hourOfDay == minHour && minute < minMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (hourOfDay  > maxHour || (hourOfDay == maxHour && minute > maxMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (validTime) {
            currentHour = hourOfDay;
            currentMinute = minute;
        }

        updateTime(currentHour, currentMinute);
        updateDialogTitle(view, currentHour, currentMinute);
    }

    private void updateDialogTitle(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String title = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        setTitle(title);
    }
}
```